# SAPUI5 - Input error on growing list, logic issue

Tags: list, data-binding, sapui5

I am having an issue with a growing list. Previously I had a normal list, but as it is limited to displaying 100 items, I need to now change this to a growing list, which works fine now and I can get over 100 items loaded when I've put the **growing="true" growingThreshold="50" growingScrollToLoad="false"** properties on the list.

But now I have an issue with one of the number inputs in the custom list, when entering a number it is not staying set (it has a liveChange event that updates a text component).

I've set a breakpoint in the controller to test and it seems to bug out when I am trying to set the data changes (red arrow on attached image).

Can anyone see the issue with the logic? If any additional code snippets are required I could provide them.

```
onReceivedQuantityChange: function (oEvent) {
            // get model and data
            var oModel = this.getOrderModel();
            var oData = oModel.getData();

            // get item from path
            var oItem = this._getOrderItemByPath(oEvent.getSource().getBindingContext(this.MODEL_ORDERS).getPath());

            // set received value
            oItem._ReceivedValue = oEvent.getParameters().newValue * (oItem.ValuationPrice / oItem.Quantity);

            // apply data changes
            oModel.setData(oData);
        },
```

[Controller code image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Bv8j.jpg)

Comment: `var iReceivedValue = iNewValue * (iValuationPrice / iQuantity)
oModel.setProperty(sItemPath + '/_ReceivedValue', iReceivedValue)`

Comment: Thanks, that allows it to work.  My JS is not fantastic, could you explain what it is doing at all? I'm also now getting iNewValue is not defined console errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
onReceivedQuantityChange: function (oEvent) {    
   var oModel = this.getOrderModel()
   var sItemPath = oEvent.getSource().getBindingContext(this.MODEL_ORDERS).getPath()
   var iValuationPrice = oModel.getProperty(sItemPath + '/ValuationPrice')
   var iQuantity = oModel.getProperty(sItemPath + '/Quantity')

   var iNewValue = oEvent.getParameters().newValue
   var iReceivedValue = iNewValue * (iValuationPrice / iQuantity) 
   oModel.setProperty(sItemPath + '/_ReceivedValue', iReceivedValue)
}
```

1. If you use `setProperty()` on the Model you're only chaning the specific Property in DataModel and Sapui5 is able to proceed bindingchanges on this Property only (and not the whole model).
2. If you get the data out of the model by `getData()` you are only getting a reference to this Object. If you change something on this Object, you don't have to set it back by `setData()` (it is already there because you used the reference of this Object).

But Sapui5 need to know that there was a specific change in datamodel and this is done by using `setProperty()`

Comment: ^^ The above didn't work. I played about and what I ended up with which worked was setting the property before setting the data.

oModel.setProperty(oItem._ReceivedValue);

Thanks for your help.